# Facebook share preview sometime picks a wrong image, although og:image is set, correct and detected

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

I'm having a problem with Facebook Like plugin.

Sometimes, when you click Share it won't display the image defined in the og:image meta tag until you close the share preview and click share again.

Here's a screenshot. og:image is assigned the url of the left image. But the preview's displaying an image of one of the related products instead.
[image: first attempt]

Now if I just close the preview and try to share again...
[image: second attempt]

I suspect that any consecutive shares of the same page - even by different clients - will display the correct image.

I tested in the Facebook debugger and it all seems to be set up properly too: og:image is detected, the width/height is fine. It even displays the correct image in the og:image property row. But every now and then it will display the wrong one in the preview.

[image: facebook debugger screenshot]

The images are stored on cloudfront and I'm using the iframe like button.

It looks like a caching or a timeout issue to me (or both combined), but i'm not sure what to do about it.

I've seen a couple of other similar questions here, but they didn't help.

Comment: What is the url to the page that Facebook pick the wrong one on? Have you tried using the debugger? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: It happens on different urls - all products on a ecommerce website. The attached screenshot is from the debugger.

Comment: It's http://themarketnz.com - I can't give the exact urls, because it doesn't always happen. I actually believe that it may _only_ happen the first time Share preview is triggered. But not for every product - maybe someone has pressed Share before me, or something...

Comment: @RicardoVieira: not really. We ended up having the staff trigger the share plugin on the most popular pages manually.

Comment: We added a new image to all our pages and suddenly FB wanted to share that image instead of the ones specified in the og:image tags. Facebook debugger says our pages are fine. Don't have a fix either...